# Server Error in '/' Application - .ASPX Web Form Application

Tags: asp.net

http://cinicraft.com/VB/WebForm1.aspx

I cannot get .aspx pages to work online, they work perfectly fine in offline mode when I'm debugging.

I published my project in Visual Studio 2010 but no matter what I try I am plagued with this parser error.

Could someone explain to me what this means?

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Assignment_1_MattAndrzejczuk.WebForm1'.
```

And why am I getting this?

I've compiled many simple WebForm applications but I can't seem to get them working online. Why can't it load the type? I've been pulling my hair out over this problem all weekend, plz help!

Comment: So replacing "Assignment_1_MattAndrzejczuk.WebForm1" with "System.Web.UI.Page" will not fix the problem, but it will at least get the web page to become viewable. The buttons don't work anymore however. Can someone explain what particular file Inherits usually goes for?

Answer (score 0):

Your not giving us a ton to go off, but if I had to guess I'm say you are missing something that was required to deploy your site.  Depending on how you done your deployment I'd imagine your either missing the bin directory or the .vb file that would accompany that .aspx file.

Comment: I've found a partial fix that at least allows the page to not get the server error. Adding System.Web.UI.Page instead of Assignment_1_MattAndrzejczuk.WebForm1 will at least let me see the page, but the buttons won't work.

Comment: that pretty much confirms it then, your code didnt get deployed.  Did you precompile or just copy the working directory from vs to your webserver?

Comment: I right clicked on the project and clicked "Publish Web Site" and Visual Studio compiled it and sent it to my ftp. How do you deploy the code so the aspx page can inherit the required code?

Comment: the publish wizard would take care of that for you, what version of .net did you target in visual studio?

Comment: I've tried .NET version 4.0 and had the same problems. For the webpage I posted at cinicraft.com I downgraded it to .NET 2.0, didn't effect anything whatsoever.